# Sorting an Array with words in different languages

Tags: string-manipulation, text, sorting, version-7, character-encoding

Array consists of words of different languages. I need to sort elements in reverse alphabetical order and make a list of elements, which consist of english letters.

Example of array which consist of english and russian words:

```
m = {"computer", "экзамен", "elephant", "стол", "bread", "телефон", 
   "exception", "desktop", "best", "колонка", "zoom", "saphire", 
   "ярость"};
```

Sorting with `Reverse@Sort[m]` and `Sort[m]` work with english words only.

`Select[m, LetterQ]` can make a list of english words.

Problem is a different language (Russian in this e.g.)

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Would you please give the output that you require for this sample input?

Comment: output 1 = {"zoom", "saphire", "exception", "elephant", "desktop", "computer", "bread", "best", "ярость", "экзамен", "телефон", "стол", "колонка"} (reverse alphabetical order)
output 2 = {"computer", "elephant", "bread", "exception", "desktop", "best", "zoom", "saphire"} (only english words)

Comment: Yes, sorted in reverse alphabetical order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
m = {"computer", "экзамен", "elephant", "стол", "bread", "телефон", "exception",
     "desktop", "best", "колонка", "zoom", "saphire", "ярость"};
```

First `Sort` it:

```
sortedm = SortBy[m, First@ToCharacterCode@# &]
```

> ```
> {"best", "bread", "computer", "desktop", "elephant", "exception", "saphire", "zoom",
>  "колонка", "стол", "телефон", "экзамен", "ярость"}
> ```

Then `Split` it:

```
splittedm = {englishWords, russianWords} = SplitBy[sortedm, 
 First@ToCharacterCode@"А" <= (First@ToCharacterCode@#) <= First@ToCharacterCode@"я" &]
```

> ```
> {{"best", "bread", "computer", "desktop", "elephant", "exception", "saphire", "zoom"}, 
>  {"колонка", "стол", "телефон", "экзамен", "ярость"}}
> ```

which can be Reversed & Flattened:

```
Flatten[Reverse /@ splittedm]
```

> ```
> {"zoom", "saphire", "exception", "elephant", "desktop", "computer", "bread", "best",
>  "ярость", "экзамен", "телефон", "стол", "колонка"}
> ```

giving the [desired](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40619/sorting-an-array-with-words-in-different-languages/40634#comment121613_40619) `Output 1`.

As you wished you can also extract the English/Russian words (even if they are sorted):

```
englishWords
```

> ```
> {"best", "bread", "computer", "desktop", "elephant", "exception", "saphire", "zoom"}
> ```

To have the unsorted words use:

```
{unsortedEnglishWords, unsortedRussianWords} = GatherBy[m, 
 First@ToCharacterCode@"А" <= (First@ToCharacterCode@#) <= First@ToCharacterCode@"я" &]
```

giving the [desired](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40619/sorting-an-array-with-words-in-different-languages/40634#comment121613_40619) `Output 2`.

---

**Note:**

The `ToCharacterCode@"А"` and `ToCharacterCode@"я"` were taken from the [Cyrillic script in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) Wiki page assuming that you are using the *Basic Cyrillic alphabet*.

"А" can be obtained with `ToString@\:0410` and "я" with `ToString@\:044F`. Both letters are meant to be first and last elements of the *Basic Cyrillic alphabet*.

Other alphabets can be used in the same way.

Comment: +1 for detailed yet concise answer.